# enable a flag or something after fileSaver.saveAs() is completed

Tags: angular, filesaver.js

My current angular2 application allows user to download a spreadsheet using filesaver.js and its working fine. But, filesaver.saveAs() is an asynchronous call and doesn't return anything like observable or promise. I need to get some flag or something which will enable after fileSaver.saveAs() is completed. (sort of hard requirement) 
Can anyone please advice/share with a sample example?

Answer (score 0):

`Filesaver.saveAs()` saves the files. The user can save a file as many times as he likes. You can proceed to do whatever you want after to have called the `saveAs()` function.